# Domain-driven design, event sourcing and evolving models

Tags: domain-driven-design, event-sourcing

Eric Evans talks a lot about evolving models in DDD so refactorings seem to be essential to DDD. When one has a relational persisted state of the world you can handle model changes by migrations that change the database schema.

How can I cope with model changes when using event sourcing? If there are incompatible changes to an aggregate that would prevent replay of events is there some sort of best practice? Or is it a just-don't?

Comment: I read this interesting post on the Event Store Blog a little while ago, maybe it helps: http://geteventstore.com/blog/20130528/why-cant-i-update-an-event/

Comment: @JefClaes I completely agree with Greg that's usually a bad idea to manipulate event history. But thanks for hinting to that article, some good ideas in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Events are just DTOs. It doesn't matter how the model changes as long as you still have one object, if the event itself doesn't change. If you need to change the event, you can 'upgrade' it with the required properties. The Apply method will know what to do with it. I can't come up with something specific without knowing details.

If the model changes so much that basically now you have 2 Aggregate Roots(AR) instead of a previous one, this means you have new different aggregates which won't be using the old events. Basically you start from the old AR, create the new ones and generate the corresponding events which will be specific to those ARs. So you don't really have a compatibility problem in this case.

Working with events is not as straightforward as 'classic' OOP and RDBMS schema, but they are more flexible if you think in business terms and treat your objects as domain concepts. Changing the model means the business concept definition or usage has changed as well, so now you're dealing with a different (new as far as the persistence is concerned) concept.

Comment: +1 this is an important concept. If the domain events are more semantic in nature then it's much more likely that changes to the domain model (and therefore the way the events are interpreted) won't have knock-on effects. *"Changing the model means the business concept definition or usage has changed as well"* I wouldn't necessarily agree with this though, given the importance of [Refactoring towards deeper insight](http://lostechies.com/seanchambers/2008/08/24/refactoring-towards-deeper-insight/).

Comment: Thanks MikeSW, I found a similar discussion [here](http://abdullin.com/journal/2011/9/27/why-event-sourcing.html) now, where the author proposes the use of Google's Protobuf, like he does [here](http://bliki.abdullin.com/event-sourcing/versioning). I thought of "incompatible" changes like removing a field from events. I think I would have to consider it in context of a real-world usage.

Comment: @mdo: Article "Why Event Sourcing?" by Rinat Abdullin has moved to http://abdullin.com/post/event-sourcing-why/, and his "Event Sourcing - Versioning" to http://abdullin.com/post/event-sourcing-versioning/.

Answer (score 4):

> If there are incompatible changes to an aggregate that would prevent replay of events

You have essentially two options in this scenario:

- Patch the older events in such a way that they are made compatible and events can be replayed from the beginning. The benefit here is that you don't lose the history but the downside is that you have to expend some effort to patch the old events.
- Take a snapshot/memento of the aggregate at the point of the schema change and "re-base" the event stream from this point onward. The benefit here is that you don't have to spend any effort (with event sourcing you most likely have a snapshot mechanism in place). The downside being that you lose the ability to replay events from before the snapshot.

As a general rule of thumb I'd say default to the second option unless you know for sure that you need to be able to go back and edit history before the schema change.

Comment: +1 for mentioning these concepts. With my current understanding of ES I would prefer to avoid the first solution for the event store is seen as a read-only event stream. At the latest if you came up with the idea of cryptographically chaining events to prevent manipulations in the event chain this would be rendered impossible :-) -- Not saying I want to do this at the moment. Using snapshots seems to go into a good direction. If you additionally keep the option to replay old events (versioned events classes?) I think you should be able to access the whole history I think ...

Answer (score 3):

I have not much expierence myself. But I saw a concept called Upcasting

> Originally a concept of object-oriented programming, where: "a subclass gets cast to it's superclass automatically when needed", the concept of upcasting can also be applied to event sourcing. To upcast an event means to transform it from its original structure to its new structure. Unlike OOP upcasting, event upcasting cannot be done in full automation because the structure of the new event is unknown to the old event. Manually written Upcasters have to be provided to specify how to upcast the old structure to the new structure.

You can refer to [Axon's doc](http://www.axonframework.org/docs/2.0/single.html#event-upcasting) for more detail

Comment: +1 for pointing to these docs, setting the answer to MikeSW's though for going into detail